# Is there a way to optimize this mysql query (update, multiple joins)?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a query that is doing what I want on a truncated dataset but when I run it on the full dataset (millions of rows) it takes forever to run.

I have two tables - microsat_table and coverage_table.

microsat_table:

```
+----+----------+-----------+---------+-------------------------------------------------+
| id | Seq_Name | SSR_Start | SSR_End | Sequence                                        |
+----+----------+-----------+---------+-------------------------------------------------+
|  2 | chr2L    |     11050 |   11067 | TTTAATTTAATTTAATTT                              |
|  3 | chr2L    |     44173 |   44187 | TATGTATGTATGTAT                                 |
|  5 | chr2L    |     54431 |   54477 | ATAATAATATAATATAATATAATATAATATATAATAATATAATAATA |
|  6 | chr2L    |     57571 |   57594 | ATATATATATATATATATATATAT                        |
|  7 | chr2L    |     72439 |   72453 | CATACATACATACAT                                 |
|  8 | chr2L    |     74028 |   74042 | ATACATACATACATA                                 |
|  9 | chr2L    |     85573 |   85587 | ATTTTATTTTATTTT                                 |
| 10 | chr2L    |     92429 |   92443 | ACATACATACATACA                                 |
| 11 | chr2L    |    138132 |  138166 | TATATAGATATATAAATATATATATATATATATAT             |
| 13 | chr2L    |    162245 |  162259 | ATACATACATACATA                                 |
+----+----------+-----------+---------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

coverage_table:

```
| Seq_Name | Start | Stop  | Coverage |
+----------+-------+-------+----------+
| chr2L    |  5716 |  5771 |        1 |
| chr2L    |  8730 |  8824 |        1 |
| chr2L    |  9894 |  9948 |        1 |
| chr2L    | 19391 | 19491 |        1 |
| chr2L    | 19575 | 19675 |        1 |
| chr2L    | 19773 | 19776 |        1 |
| chr2L    | 19776 | 19872 |        2 |
| chr2L    | 21920 | 21959 |        1 |
| chr2L    | 21959 | 22020 |        2 |
| chr2L    | 22020 | 22059 |        1 |
+----------+-------+-------+----------+
```

I want to add a column to the microsat_table which calculates the average coverage (from the coverage_table) over all rows where the Start and Stop values in the coverage table fall within the SSR_Start and SSR_End values in the microsat_table.

Example result:

```
+-----+----------+-----------+---------+--------------------------------+---------+
| id  | Seq_Name | SSR_Start | SSR_End | Sequence                       | avg     |
+-----+----------+-----------+---------+--------------------------------+---------+
|  53 | chr2L    |    402489 |  402503 | AAAACAAAACAAAAC                |  3.0000 |
|  64 | chr2L    |    447214 |  447233 | CAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCAGCA           |  8.0000 |
|  66 | chr2L    |    457839 |  457868 | CAGCAGCAGCAACAGCAGCAGCAGGCAGCA |  2.0000 |
| 105 | chr2L    |    579589 |  579603 | TCGAATCGAATCGAA                | 11.0000 |
| 123 | chr2L    |    628484 |  628501 | TAATGTTAATGTTAATGT             |  6.0000 |
+-----+----------+-----------+---------+--------------------------------+---------+
```

My query is:

```
UPDATE microsat_table
JOIN 
   (SELECT m.id, SUM(p.Coverage)/count(p.Start) 
      AS avg FROM microsat_table m  
      LEFT OUTER JOIN coverage_table p 
      ON m.Seq_Name LIKE p.Seq_Name 
      WHERE m.Seq_Name LIKE p.Seq_Name GROUP BY m.id) AS qt 
ON microsat_table.id = qt.id 
SET microsat_table.avg = qt.avg;
```

Explain results for the truncated table:

```
+----+-------------+----------------------+------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+--------------------------------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                | partitions | type  | possible_keys                                     | key         | key_len | ref                            | rows   | filtered | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+----------------------+------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+--------------------------------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | UPDATE      | microsat_table_short | NULL       | ALL   | PRIMARY                                           | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                           |  40356 |   100.00 | NULL                                               |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>           | NULL       | ref   | <auto_key0>                                       | <auto_key0> | 4       | testdb.microsat_table_short.id |   1236 |   100.00 | NULL                                               |
|  2 | DERIVED     | m                    | NULL       | index | PRIMARY,Sequence,Seq_Name,Motif,SSR_Start,SSR_End | Seq_Name    | 53      | NULL                           |  40356 |   100.00 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort       |
|  2 | DERIVED     | p                    | NULL       | ALL   | NULL                                              | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                           | 100163 |     1.23 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
+----+-------------+----------------------+------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+--------------------------------+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

I added indexes (including trying HASH and BTREE indexes) which sped it up considerably, but I've let it run for 1.5 days on the larger dataset and it still didn't finish.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to make it run faster?

Thanks!!

Comment: Please also add the query plan for the actual table since that's what's being slow

Comment: The result set doesn't correspond to the data set. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few relatively minor infelicities in your code. However the big problem is that while you say you want to calculate "the average coverage (from the coverage_table) over all rows where the Start and Stop values in the coverage table fall within the SSR_Start and SSR_End values in the microsat_table" you don't actually seem to limit the query to doing that. Instead you only coded a match on `Seq_Name`.

The code below attempts to fix that (I used `>=` and `<=` which may not be what you need) and the other more minor bits:

```
UPDATE microsat_table
JOIN 
   (
   SELECT
       m.id,
       AVG(p.Coverage) AS avg -- MySQL has it's own average function
   FROM
       microsat_table m  
       INNER JOIN coverage_table p ON -- Change to INNER JOIN, your old WHERE clause had this effect anyway
           m.Seq_Name = p.Seq_Name -- Use '=' not 'Like' when looking for an exact match
   WHERE
        p.Start >= m.SSR_Start -- This WHERE clause is the most important change 
        AND p.End <= m.SSR_End -- You omitted it in your version
   GROUP BY
       m.id) AS qt 
ON microsat_table.id = qt.id 
SET microsat_table.avg = qt.avg;
```

Comment: Until this recommendation has been addressed (and verified), the original question about indexes cannot be answered.

Comment: Thanks!! It shortened the query from 40s to 8s in the command line! For some reason when I run the exact same query in my script it lengthens it to 900 seconds :-/. I'm trying to figure out what is going on there, but it seems like it has to be the script, not the query.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe updating the table in 1 big transaction is simply too much for the system? (what is the size of the table you're updating?) You could try doing it in blocks. I'd also go for a simple sub-select here, seems easier to read IMHO.

Also take note of Steve Lovell's remark that your query doesn't seem to care about the start/stop columns. Since you probably forgot it by accident I've added it here too, removing it shouldn't be too difficult =)

```
DECLARE @min_id int,
        @max_id int,
        @blocksize int

SELECT @min_id = MIN(id),
       @max_id = MAX(id),
       @blocksize = 100000 -- adapt as needed
  FROM microsat_table

WHILE @min_id <= @max_id
    BEGIN

        UPDATE microsat_table
           SET microsat_table.avg = ((SELECT SUM(p.Coverage)/count(p.Start) AS avg 
                                        FROM microsat_table m  
                                        LEFT OUTER JOIN coverage_table p 
                                                     ON m.Seq_Name LIKE p.Seq_Name -- if possble use '=' here instead of LIKE
                                                    AND p.Start >= m.SSR_Start -- flagrantly "stolen" from Steve Lovell's answer
                                                    AND p.End   <= m.SSR_End
                                       WHERE m.id = microsat_table.id) 
        -- limit update to this block:
         WHERE microsat_table.id BETWEEN @min_id AND (@min_id + @blocksize - 1)

        -- prepare for next block
        SELECT @min_id = @min_id + @blocksize
    END
```

You probably want the primary key on the `id` field of `microsat_table` and on the `Seq_name` + `Start` column of the `coverage_table`.

Comment: Thanks!! Yes, I did forget it by accident :-). Question - I've never worked with mysql stored procedures and variables before, do I need to put all of the code into a function or can I just enter it into the command line as is? I get a syntax error when I enter it as, and also tried putting it into a function which also gave me a syntax error. I could definitely be doing the function declaration incorrectly since I've never worked with them before...

Comment: I'll admit being used to MSSQL. It seems I naively but wrongly assumed this was pretty much ANSI SQL and would work without too much hassle on MySQL too. Trying to get it to run on sqlfiddle shows I was very wrong... I'll try to get it working on MySQL and then adapt my code... (this might take a while =)